# If Two cells match: Return from third cell for sorting data

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have two data from two instances, I want to merge that data based on two cells in a row if it is getting matched in the second instance.

In the excel, refer attached Image, If the values in the A2 and B2 match with the AB and AC array, I need to pick the cell value in the corresponding row to X2.

I tried writing the formula as

> =INDEX($AE$2:$AE$628,MATCH(A2&B2,$AB$2:$AB$628&$AC$2:$AC$628,0))

But I'm getting response as #Value!

[image: Excel Sheet]

Comment: As is frequently the case, it is difficult to help you as I cannot paste your screenshot into my workbook, but on you screenshot, you are **not** using the same formula as in your question. Probably your `MATCH` function is not returning a valid number. Try running that part all by itself. And to make your data useful for troubleshooting, edit your question to post a representative subset as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: I solved it just now. Thanks for your help.
{=INDEX($AE$2:$AE$628,MATCH(A2&B2,$AB$2:$AB$628&$AC$2:$AC$628,0))}

After entering the equation Ctrl +Shift + Enter should be done. 

This solves the issue. with this only the '&' in the match function can be solved by the excel.